# Change MySQL date format via Update

Tags: mysql, date, sql-update

I try to get following query to work, but 0 rows are affected:

```
UPDATE table_x 
SET sql_date = DATE(STR_TO_DATE(date_string,'%Y-%m-%d')) 
WHERE sql_date = '0000-00-00'
```

The date format in the column date_string is: '%d.%m.%Y'

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: "The date format in the column date_string is: '%d.%m.%Y'" - Then why are you using `'%Y-%m-%d'` in your query?

Comment: f.... I thought I have to use the target format. But of course that was a silly idea. Thanks for that hint.

Answer (score 0):

your column date_string is already "yyyy-dd-mm", then why you want to update.
Still you can compare date as per below:

```
UPDATE table_x set sql_date = DATE(STR_TO_DATE(date_string,'%Y-%m-%d'))
WHERE date(sql_date) = '0000-00-00';
```

SO it will skip time stamp and compare only date with your passes date.
Date function will get only date from the stored date. So if "1992-11-06 00:00:00" is stored in DB then it will compare only "1992-11-06".

Answer (score 0):

You say `date_string` is in the format `'%d.%m.%Y'`. But you are mistakenly specifying `'%Y-%m-%d'` for `STR_TO_DATE` instead. Moreover when you have converted the string to date you apply `DATE` on this date. Why?

```
UPDATE table_x 
SET sql_date = STR_TO_DATE(date_string, '%d.%m.%Y')
WHERE sql_date = '0000-00-00';
```

Comment: Thanks. Like Paul Siegel commented. I had not used my little brain enough.